# How to toggle a div to slide up and down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to slide toggle a hidden DIV when a user hover overs some link buttons.

JavaScript:

```
$(function () { // DOM ready shorthand

            var $content = $(".sliderText");
            var $contentdiv = $(".sliderContent");

            var $homeToggle = $("#home");
            var $listToggle = $("#list");

            $contentdiv.hide();

            $homeToggle.hover(function () {
                $content.Text("Navigate to Home");
                $contentdiv.stop().slideToggle();
            });
            $listToggle.hover(function () {
                $content.Text("SDSFDFS");
                $contentdiv.stop().slideToggle();
            });
        });
```

CSS:

```
    .sliderContent {
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        border: 2px dotted #00039a;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
                <div class="container" id="homeDIV" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">
                    <a id="home" title="Navigate to home page" href="Default.aspx">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="listDIV" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">
                    <a id="list" title="Shows all the fields and their indexes per PDF form in the folder" href="ListFormFields.aspx">List PDF Form Fields</a>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="createDIV" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">
                    <a id="create" title="Allows user to enter the data in HTML/ASP.NET controls to be populated in PDF forms" href="CreateW9.aspx">Create PDF From Fill-In</a>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="queryDIV" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">
                    <a id="query" title="Auto-generates the PDF based on a search by the user" href="PDFQueryCreate.aspx">Create PDF Quering a DataBase</a>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="displayDIV" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">
                    <a id="display" title="" href="PDFAllFilesDisplay.aspx">Display All Completed PDF Files</a>
                </div>
                <div class="container" id="emailDIV" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">
                    <a title="Contact the developer for support" href="mailto:zh@as.com">Email Support</a>
                </div>
                <div id="showText" class="sliderContent" runat="server" clientidmode="Static">
                    <span class="sliderText"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

What I am looking to achieve is when a user hovers over any of the `<a>` the div with the ID `showText` will expand by sliding down and display the contents.

Right now when I hover over, nothing happens.

How do I achieve it?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mt4m2/

Issue shown here: http://youtu.be/68_kzCygYg4

Comment: Could it be because you're hiding the div that should be sliding?? `$contentdiv.hide();`

Comment: I added the JSFiddle with an update but when you hover over home and then to List quickly the DIV goes crazy. If you hover over home and then move your mouse somewhere else and then back to the list, it works fine.

Comment: the fiddle appears to be working to me. when I hover over the home and then list, the text in the slider div is changed. Nothing crazy...

Comment: Fiddle seems like normal behavior for me, using Chrome v35 -- hovering over Home and then quickly to List simply changes the content of the slid-out div.

Comment: Weird. With the proper styling that's not happening to me. I will update my JSFiddle.

Comment: Something wrong with my page it seems. I am using ASP.NET. The only time it works for me is I have to completely go out of the DIV for the menu and come back to the second menu selection and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no function `content.Text`, using `content.text`

It works, look: http://jsfiddle.net/x4My2/1/

Comment: I wish I can post a video of what it looks like in my browser.

Comment: ok, show. Im was wrong: there are no reason associated with prefix, there are wrong name of function.

Comment: http://youtu.be/68_kzCygYg4 which shows what is happening in my browser for my site.

Comment: which browser? I'm using chrome, it looks good for me here: http://jsfiddle.net/x4My2/1/

Comment: Using chrome as well as IE and FF.

Comment: did you replace\delete something before show us your code?

Comment: Nope that is the code that is on my page. and I am using jquery 1.11.0 which is pretty much almost the latest version

Comment: Uh oh, I think this is a animation bug. So bad, that I can't see your monitor right now :'( Even for ver 1.11.0 it works good for me...

Comment: Even the JSFiddle I created with my code works fine but it's when in my page it doesnt work :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56613/discussion-between-deniskoronets-and-searchforknowledge).